# How to add new values to columns, if condition from another columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, pyspark, pandas-groupby

I want to group the values from one column to another. My idea is to do new column ith continents. I have the lists witf countries. e.g Poland -> Europe,  France ->

I have tried different methods, and every time I get in new column values ‘Other' or none. Can You help me?

```html
europe = ['England','France','Germany','Greece','Holand-Netherlands',
          'Hungary',' Ireland',' Italy','Poland','Portugal',' Scotland','Yugoslavia']

asia = ['Cambodia','China','Hong Kong','India','Iran','Japan',
        'Laos','Philippines','South Korea','Taiwan','Thailand','Vietnam']

north_america = ['Canada','Cuba','Dominican-Republic','El-Salvador','Guatemala','Haiti',
                 'Honduras','Jamaica','Mexico','Nicaragua','Outlying-U S (Guam USVI etc)',
                 'Panama','Puerto-Rico','Trinadad&Tobago']       
other = ['?']

south_america = ['Columbia','Ecuador','Peru']

unitet_states = ['United-States']


def Continent (row):
    if row['country of birth self'] in europe:
        return 'Europe'
    elif row['country of birth self'] in north_america:
        return 'North America'
    elif row['country of birth self'] in asia:
        return 'Asia'
    elif row['country of birth self'] in south_america:
        return 'South America'
    elif row['country of birth self'] in unitet_states:
        return 'United-States'
    else:
        return 'Other'
    
data_train_pandas['continent'] = data_train_pandas.apply(lambda row: Continent (row), axis=1)    
data_train_pandas[['country of birth self','continent']]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried out your code and it works for me. Please check if there are any leading or trailing spaces for values in column `country of birth self`.

Comment: Yes, it works correct, but gave not good output.  In every columns is display value "Other", it is not correct. For example for Poland should by Europe, for United States ->United-States

Comment: I am getting correct output. E.g., `Poland -> Europe` & `United-States -> United-States`. That's why I am thinking there might be some unwanted space, hidden characters in the `column of birth self` column, which makes it fail the if else conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas solution with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with helper `dictionary` `d1` created by dict comprehension with dictionary `d`:

```
d = {'Europe':europe,
     'Asia':asia,
     'North America':north_america,
     'South America':south_america,
     'United-States':unitet_states
     }

d1 = {x: k for k, v in d.items() for x in v}

data_train_pandas['continent'] = (data_train_pandas['country of birth self']
                                     .str.strip()
                                     .map(d1)
                                     .fillna('Other'))
```

Comment: Sorry, what is k and v?

Comment: @Dorota-Toskania - It is key and value of dict `d`

Comment: I still have 'Other" in all rows.

Comment: @Dorota-Toskania What is `print(data_train_pandas['country of birth self'].head().tolist())`?

Comment: [' United-States', ' United-States', ' Vietnam', ' United-States', ' United-States']

Comment: But for:

print(data_train_pandas['continent'].head().tolist())

['Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other', 'Other']

Comment: @Dorota-Toskania - answer was edited, need `str.strip` for remove trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here: https://towardsdatascience.com/using-python-to-create-a-world-map-from-a-list-of-country-names-cd7480d03b10

You could add geographical features like continents to your DF.

```
#installation
pip install pycountry-convert
#function to convert to alpah2 country codes and continents from pycountry_convert import country_alpha2_to_continent_code, country_name_to_country_alpha2 def get_continent(col):
    try:
        cn_a2_code =  country_name_to_country_alpha2(col)
    except:
        cn_a2_code = 'Unknown' 
    try:
        cn_continent = country_alpha2_to_continent_code(cn_a2_code)
    except:
        cn_continent = 'Unknown' 
    return (cn_a2_code, cn_continent)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have the original dataset where the country values are in the ['country of birth self'] column. In feature engineering, I want to create a new column with continent names for each country. But for the USA it will be USA, not North America.